# 3DES Encryption result different from example

Tags: swift, encryption, encoding, character-encoding, 3des

I have an example for a 3DES encryption that I have to follow in order to authenticate on NFC cards. Here is the example:[image]

So 51E764602678DF2B becomes 577293FD2F34CA51 with key = 49454D4B41455242214E4143554F5946 and IV = 0000000000000000
I succeed to have the right result on this site:
http://tripledes.online-domain-tools.com/

I tried on swift with https://github.com/sgl0v/SCrypto as follow:

```
func testScrypto() {
    let plaintext = "51E764602678DF2B".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let sharedSecretKey = "49454D4B41455242214E4143".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let IV = "0000000000000000".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    let ciphertext = try! plaintext.encrypt(.tripleDES, options: .PKCS7Padding, key: sharedSecretKey, iv: IV)     

    let plaintext2 = try! ciphertext.decrypt(.tripleDES, options: .PKCS7Padding, key: sharedSecretKey, iv: IV)

    print("cipher = \(ciphertext.hexString())")
    print("plaintext2 = \(plaintext2.hexString())")
}

public extension Data {

func bytesArray<T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>() -> [T] {
    var bytes = Array<T>(repeating: 0, count: self.count)
    (self as NSData).getBytes(&bytes, length:self.count * MemoryLayout<T>.size)
    return bytes
}

func hexString() -> String {
    let hexString = NSMutableString()
    let bytes: [UInt8] = self.bytesArray()
    for byte in bytes {
        hexString.appendFormat("%02x", UInt(byte))
    }
    return hexString as String
}
}
```

and the result is:

```
cipher = d4c4a9637bcb4a435982330a42d1357b9e4539886a983535
plaintext2 = 35314537363436303236373844463242
```

35314537363436303236373844463242 is 51E764602678DF2B if i convert from hexstring to plaintext but the other string is not 577293FD2F34CA51 at all

I also tried this lib https://www.example-code.com/swift/crypt2_3des.asp 
but the result is still wrong

I don't know if anybody has an idea how to do this on swift or is an expert in encryption ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed to fix the issue
The issue was that the key was only 16 bytes and need to be 24, so I guess it was randomly filled but it was expected to be the first 8 bytes to be put back at the end of the 16 in order to do 24 ?

like this it works:

```
func fillKey(keyLength: size_t, key: Data) -> Data {
    let missingBytes = keyLength - key.count
    if missingBytes > 0 {
        let keyBytes = (key as NSData).bytes
        var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: UInt8(0), count: keyLength)
        memccpy(&bytes[0], keyBytes.advanced(by: 0), Int32(key.count), key.count)
        memccpy(&bytes[key.count], keyBytes.advanced(by: 0), Int32(missingBytes), missingBytes)
        return Data(bytes: bytes)
    } else {
        return key
    }
}

func my3DESEncrypt(encryptData: String, key: String, iv: String) -> Data? {
    var myKeyData : Data = key.hexadecimal()!
    let myIvData : Data = iv.hexadecimal()!
    var myRawData : Data = encryptData.hexadecimal()!
    let buffer_size : size_t = myRawData.count + kCCBlockSize3DES
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: UInt8(0), count: buffer_size)
    var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = 0
    let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

    myKeyData = self.fillKey(keyLength: keyLength, key: myKeyData)
    let Crypto_status: CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, (myKeyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength, (myIvData as NSData).bytes, (myRawData as NSData).bytes, myRawData.count, &buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)
    if UInt32(Crypto_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        let data = Data(bytes: buffer, count: num_bytes_encrypted)
        return data
    } else{
        return nil
    }
}


func my3DESDecrypt(decryptData : Data, key: String, iv: String) -> Data? {
    let mydata_len : Int = decryptData.count
    var myKeyData : Data = key.hexadecimal()!
    let myIvData : Data = iv.hexadecimal()!

    let buffer_size : size_t = mydata_len+kCCBlockSize3DES
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: UInt8(0), count: buffer_size)
    var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)


    myKeyData = self.fillKey(keyLength: keyLength, key: myKeyData)
    let decrypt_status : CCCryptorStatus = CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, (myKeyData as NSData).bytes, keyLength, (myIvData as NSData).bytes, (decryptData as NSData).bytes, mydata_len, &buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

    if UInt32(decrypt_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){
        let data = Data(bytes: buffer, count: num_bytes_encrypted)
        return data
    } else{
        return nil

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The plaintext data and key that have been provided are encoded in hexadecimals. You are however encoding them as UTF-8 text, which is not the same thing.

Comment: I don't see any hexadecimal option in the encoding ?

Comment: That's correct, so maybe you need a library. The functionality is not in the string class because this is more about encoding binary to text and decoding it later. UTF-8 for instance is encoding the string to binary. Hence the tag [tag:character-encoding] for UTF-8 and the tag [tag:encoding] for things like hexadecimals and base 64.

Comment: I found some extension to string to convert hexadecimal string to Data but it's not working either so i guess it's not what i'm looking for haha